# How to display a category of products on sale

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to add a link on my Magento 1.9 site that shows all the products on sale across all categories. I found the following article that shows how to display the products on sale in the current category by overwriting the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`.

http://inchoo.net/magento/more-flexible-approach-for-listing-out-products-on-sale-in-magento/

So this got me thinking. Rather than trying to create a new page to display the products on sale, create a category called Sale. Then rewrite the  `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` method and check if the current category is the Sale category, and set `$this->_productCollection` to a collection that contains all the products on sale.

I'm having a few problems trying to get this to work.

In fact I'm struggling to get a collection of all the products that are displayed in my categories so I can then filter it down so it just contains the products on sale. At the moment my code sets `$this->_productCollection` to a collection that contains all the products on the site (including the Simple Products of my Configurable Products). I just want the Products that are displayed in my categories.

Can someone please show me how to get all the products that are on sale on my site and how to set `$this->_productCollection` so the Sale products are displayed?

I've pasted the code I've written so far below

**app\code\local\CompanyName\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php**

```
<?php
class CompanyName_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }

            // Check if the current category is the Sale category
            if ($layer->getCurrentCategory()->getId() == '14') {

                // Get all categories
                Mage::log('Root Category IDs');
                $rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('2');
                $subCategories = explode(",", $rootCategory->getAllChildren());

                // Get all products
                $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
                $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                $products->joinField('category_id',
                    'catalog/category_product',
                    'category_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left'
                );
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $subCategories));
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
                $this->_productCollection = $products;

                // Show only the products on sale
                //$this->_productCollection
                //     ->addFinalPrice()
                //     ->getSelect()
                //     ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');

            } else {
                $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
            }

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

**app\etc\modules\CompanyName_Catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </CompanyName_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\CompanyName\Catalog\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <companyname_catalog>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </companyname_catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>CompanyName_Catalog_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set product collection for On Sale products upto current date :

```
    $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addTaxPercents()          
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('date'=>true, 'from'=> $todayDate));

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    $products->setPageSize($this->getConfig('qty'))->setCurPage(1);
    $this->setProductCollection($products);
```